# getting StaleElementException while running axe using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am using axe(version 4.0.0) with my selenium tests, however I am getting stale element exception intermittently when i am trying to analyze the web page. Using below code

```
public static boolean runAxeReport(CucumberContext context, String outputFileName) throws Exception
{

    AxeBuilder builder = new AxeBuilder().withTags(tags);

    Results result =builder.analyze(context.driver);

    List<Rule> violations = result.getViolations();

    if(violations.size()>0)
    {
        AxeReporter.writeResultsToJsonFile(outputDirectory + "/" + outputFileName, result);
    }

    return false;

}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to inject axe script

at com.deque.html.axecore.selenium.AxeBuilder.analyzeRawContext(AxeBuilder.java:436)
at com.deque.html.axecore.selenium.AxeBuilder.analyze(AxeBuilder.java:390)
at com.automation.pom.AxeRun.runAxeReport(AxeRun.java:50)
at com.automation.cucumber.loginAmazon_stepdef.navigate_to_url(loginAmazon_stepdef.java:41)
at ✽.User is on "https://www.amazon.co.uk"(file:///C:/Framework/features/SearchProduct.feature:5)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: headless chrome=88.0.4324.182)
```

Comment: Show us your stack trace

Comment: Share the stacktrace

Comment: Got it working with latest axe dependency ->  <dependency>
            <groupId>com.deque.html.axe-core</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core-maven-html/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/deque/html/axecore/selenium/AxeExampleUnitTest.java

Comment: Sorry I am again getting stale element exception

Comment: Villa_7,  Alexey R, added the stack trace